# How to validate if a map field has a certain key in the Ecto model (instead of in the controller)?

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to store a map as a field into my database (the data source is JSON). For the data to be valid, the JSON needs to have a certain key, i.e. the key has to be present in the converted Elixir map as well.

It should be ideal to perform this validation within the model module instead of manually checking for the key within the controller and then adding the error with `add_error`. However, I've looked into the Ecto documentation but so far the validations seem to be all about simple fields that are not of `map` type themselves, e.g. checking whether the `string` field matches a certain regex. I don't seem to be able to find an easy way to do this. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own validation functions, for an example look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331889/2064880 or here https://medium.com/@QuantLayer/writing-custom-validations-for-ecto-changesets-4971881c7684.

So for your use case maybe something like this would work:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(attrs, [:map_field])
  |> validate_key_exists()
end

defp validate_key_exists(%Ecto.Changeset{changes:
      %{map_field: %{the_special_key: _value}}} = changeset) do
  changeset
end
defp validate_key_exists(changeset) do
  add_error(changeset, :map_field, "Missing special key.")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. For some reason your code didn't work... Seems that Elixir wasn't able to pattern match the nested key, or maybe there're some other complications. But following the method listed in that other SO answer, I was able to retrieve the `:map_field` from the changeset first, and then use `Map.has_key?` to check for `the_special_key`, which worked.